# What's the difference between Rect and Rectangle?

Tags: java, android

I noticed that I can't use `Rectangle` in Android Studios because it doesn't support Java 8, but Android has `Rect` instead.

All of the tutorials I've seen were for general Java, so they didn't use Android's `Rect`.

Are there any major differences between `Rect` and `Rectangle` or can they be used interchangeably when I code? (Assuming I replace `Rectangle` with `Rect`, of course.)

NOTE : I'm using them to check for object collision.

Comment: Read the javadoc of Rest. Read the javadoc of Rectangle. Compare them. Note that Rectangle exists since Java 1.0. The fact that it's not in Android has nothing to do with Android not supporting Java 8. It has everything to do with Android not supporting AWT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rectangle is a class from Java 2D API.

Rect (and RectF) is a class from Android Draw API.

Java Rectangles are expressed as (xPos, yPos, width, height).

Android Rects are expressed as (left, top, right, bottom).

You must use the Android one.

To convert from (xywh) to (ltrb) the following is necessary:

Rect = new Rect(x, y, x + w, y + h);